# What is the connotation of slumber?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs

I've always thought "to slumber" meant to sleep deeply or for a long period of time. Several colloquial but less reputable dictionaries agree with me (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slumber, http://www.yourdictionary.com/slumber) but Merriam-Webster and the OED disagree, defining slumber as "to sleep lightly" and "to sleep, esp. to sleep lightly; to doze or drowse," respectively.

Which is correct in modern usage?

Answer (score 3):

It just means *sleep*. Although it is not an archaism, the word isn't used much in everyday English. Google Ngram shows the usage of *slumber* compared with *sleep*.

[image]

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sleep%2Cslumber&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslumber%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

It is an old verb, not  commonly used nowadays:

[Slumber](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=slumber):

> - mid-14c. alteration of slumeren (mid-13c.), frequentative form of slumen ***"to doze," probably from Old English sluma "light sleep"***  (compare Middle Dutch slumen, Dutch sluimeren, German schlummern "to slumber"). ***Frequentative on the notion of "intermittent light sleep."*** (Etymonline)

[To slumber](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slumber) literary :

> - Sleep - 
>     *‘Sleeping Beauty slumbered in her forest castle’
>     figurative ‘the village street slumbered under the afternoon sun’*' (ODO)